# Symfony2 ORM OneToOne relation, join

Tags: symfony, join

I have entity:

```
class RegionalPartner
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="direction_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Direction")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="direction_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $directionId;

...
```

And the target of relation:

```
class Direction
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
.....
```

I have a repository:

```
    class RegionalPartnerRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllWithNames()
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
                SELECT 
                    r
                FROM 
                    AstRegionalPartnerBundle:RegionalPartner r 
                JOIN 
                    r.directionId d
                ');
            //->setParameters($params);

        return $query->getResult();
```

There is a error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 108 near 'd': Error: Class Ast\RegionalPartnerBundle\Entity\RegionalPartner has no association named directionId
```

What should i do to make the right code of the relation (need to get the name of "direction" to the "RegionalPartner" entity)?

And where is the documentation of joins in that ORM ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the QueryBuilder and set a correct select

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('r')
     ->select('d.name')
     ->innerJoin('r.directionId', 'd')
```

Try to name you properties well. So directionId -> direction

Comment: Thanks for the remark, but realy i do not need join here if my association is work fine. The trouble was in the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
class RegionalPartner
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Direction")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="direction_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $directionId;

...
```

Deleted part of the annotation:

```
* @ORM\Column(name="direction_id", type="integer")
```